# Finding the largest groups with conditions after using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
        'b': [20, 20, 20,-70, 70, -10, -10, -1, -1],
    }
)
```

And this is the output that I want. I want to create a dataframe with two rows:

```
    direction   length  sum
0   long        3        60
1   short       2       -20
```

I want to get the largest streak of positive (long) and negative(short) numbers in `b`. And then get the `length` and `sum` of `b` values in that streak and create a new dataframe. Note that if for example the largest streak is two and there are more than one streak with that size, I want the streak that its sum of `b` is more that the rest.

In my `df`, the largest long streak is the first three values. And the largest short streak is two. Since there are more than one streak with that size, I want the one that its `sum` is more. So I want rows 5 and 6.

This is what I have tried but I don't know how to follow up:

```
df['streak'] = df['b'].ne(df['b'].shift()).cumsum()
df['size'] = df.groupby('streak')['b'].transform('size')

   a   b  streak  size
0  a  20       1     3
1  a  20       1     3
2  a  20       1     3
3  c -70       2     1
4  b  70       3     1
5  a -10       4     2
6  a -10       4     2
7  b  -1       5     2
8  c  -1       5     2
```

Comment: what is the relevance of column a?

Comment: @Mark It is not relevant. I wanted it to look like my actual data just in case.

Comment: If `a` is not relevant, you don't have to include it in the `groupby` in my answer. However if you can have something like a/1,a/1,a/1,b/1 and this should be 2 groups (3+1) not 1 (4), then keep `a` as additional grouper.

Comment: @mozway I know. I can edit these things on my own. Your answers are perfect. And you are not even using a pc right now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use several `groupby` operations, one to find the streaks, one to [`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) the length and sum, and one to filter the output with [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) on the largest length:

```
group = df['b'].ne(df['b'].shift()).cumsum()

out = (df
   .assign(direction=np.sign(df['b']))
   .replace({'direction': {1: 'long', -1: 'short'}})
   .groupby(['a', 'direction', group], as_index=False)
   .agg(length=('b', 'count'),
        sum=('b', 'sum'))
   .sort_values(by='sum', key=abs, ascending=False)
   .loc[lambda d: d.groupby('direction')['length'].idxmax(),
        ['direction', 'length', 'sum']]
       )
```

Output:

```
  direction  length  sum
0      long       3   60
1     short       2  -20
```

Intermediate before the final [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
   a direction  length  sum
0  a      long       3   60
1  a     short       2  -20
2  b      long       1   70
3  b     short       1   -1
4  c     short       1  -70
5  c     short       1   -1
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I have a question about the styling of your code and the way you indent. Is that the standard way to do it? Is it a pro thing? ;) I like your answers and style.

Comment: @Amir this is called method chaining, I like to have 1 command/method per row. Here I indented manually as I was typing on my phone. You can also use `black` or an equivalent tool to do this automatically ;)

Comment: @mozway I think this code should be modified. It does not give the desired result when applied to the following example.
`df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'b': [20, 20, 20,-70, 70, -1, -1, -10, -10]})`

Comment: @mozway Yes. Nick`s solution works.

Comment: @PandaKim I overlooked this part, then you can indeed add a sorting step

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative solution using [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to sort based on the length and sum of the streak rather than a second groupby:

```
group = df['b'].ne(df['b'].shift()).cumsum()

out = (df
    .assign(direction=np.where(df['b'] >= 0, 'long', 'short'))
    .groupby(['direction', group], as_index=False)
    .agg(length=('b','size'),sum=('b','sum'))
    .sort_values(['length', 'sum'], key=lambda s:s.abs(), ascending=False)
    .drop_duplicates('direction')
)
```

Output:

```
  direction  length  sum
0      long       3   60
3     short       2  -20
```

Comment: @Amir apologies if you had tried to use this code, I realised during the night that I had made an error in it, which I have corrected now.